# Button Opening a New Xml Page

Tags: android

I have an Android App That requires a button to open up a new xml page. This is what it's like now, could someone add the necessary code to make it open Page2Activity when I click on the button? Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Void onClick;View arg0; {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    };

    }
```

I figured this out using this method : ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094103/linking-xml-pages-with-layout*** ,but I will try All of yours as well.

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you. Try a paid service.

Comment: @Sam it seems you're wrong...

Comment: @sam Thank you SOOOOOOO Much and by that I mean that doesn't help. I just need to know the onclick procedure...

Comment: Forgive me if I seemed rude. According to the TOS, this is a forum for questions you have attempted yourself and researched thoroughly but to no avail. Your `TODO` statement & "someone add the necessary code" does not suggest thorough effort. If you are looking for an onClickListener and startActivity() example, please double check the Related column (over there -->), maybe [How do I make a button switch to a new activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091418/how-do-i-make-a-button-switch-to-a-new-activity). Please don't let my bluntness discourage you from contributing here. Good luck!

Comment: I have seen quite a few instances, but I have no Idea how to adapt it to work with my application...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public void handleClick(View v){
    //Create an intent to start the new activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,Page2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then create a new cLass called `Page2Activity`.

Hope this helps and don't forget to add your activity to the manifest file.

Comment: I tried it and maybe messed up the placement. Where in the code would I put this code?

Comment: @CreeperHunter put  this code instead of (Void on Click) in MainActivity

Comment: @CreeperHunter also put this line in Xml show button :( android:onClick="handleClick" ), hope this clear.

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean something like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent("com.myaction");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: just pointing this out, but this is full of errors if I put in in Eclipse.

Comment: you need to have a button called `button1` in you layout XML. + you need to have an activity with the action name `"com.action"`

Comment: some minor errors, edited the vode and now it'll work perfectly